# Rule which would allow to enter just only [a-z] letters in Yii2

Tags: yii2

In my Yii2 entry form I need to allow for the user to enter just only letters [a-z]. I know that I need to define the rule in my `model` correctly, I'm trying but I'm doing something wrong.

Here is my rule now:

```
['name', 'required', 'except' => self::SCENARIO_SEARCH],
['name', 'string', 'max' => 255],
['name', 'match',
   'pattern' => '/[a-z]/',
   'message' => 'Invalid characters in username.',
],
```

Thank you for the help

Comment: is answer helpful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use following pattern:

```
['name', 'match', 'pattern' => '/^[a-z]+$/', 'message' => 'Invalid characters in username.'],
```

To make sure that Yii's matching is working, you can test it by writing @ (for example) as first character. Then, you can see that, validation works. So the problem is with your pattern.